# Qimage crop area without changing a scale or aspect ratio(the 100px at the bottom stays blank)

Tags: python, pyside

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9HFN.jpg)
When I change the parameters manually, it stretches and it just move the field that I am painting on, but not the size of the image

```
    top = 400
    left = 400
    width = 800
    height = 600
    

    self.setWindowTitle("Paint")
    self.setGeometry(top, left, width, height)
    self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)
    self.image.fill(Qt.white)
```

#------------------

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    canvasPainter = QPainter(self)
    canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is "the field that I am painting on"? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: So the problem is that I am making a painting app and I have all the widgets for changing color and stuff like that at the bottom, and right now I am able to paint over them and that is something I want to prevent. I think changing the "working side" area by -100 px at the bottom would fix that, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: You're probably painting on the wrong widget (maybe the main window). As already said, you need to provide a MRE.